# "Error, could not load media" when attempting to call Photos app crop intent sending Uri that points to files dir

Tags: android, android-intent, crop, photos, android-implicit-intent

**What I'm attempting to do:**

Select a photo from my Facebook photos and then send that photo to the native Photo editing experience (the Photos app)

**Here are the steps I'm taking:**

1. Get url for photo from fb
2. Use Picasso to fetch image url into Bitmap
3. Store that Bitmap to a file on disk in my app specific /data/data/ dir
4. Create a Uri from that file path
5. Send that Uri as the data part of the implicit Intent for the "com.android.camera.action.CROP" action

I'm guessing the problem is that the Photos app doesn't have permission to access the file in my /data/data dir, but I'm curious if anyone can confirm that is indeed the problem and, if so, how you solved it. I'm guessing the solution is to save the file to the SD card instead so that the Photos app can access it?

Ok, here's some code ...

**After I've written the Bitmap to file, I call this to get Uri**

```
Uri pictureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(path))
```

**I then send that Uri to the crop intent like so**

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        intent.setDataAndType(pictureUri, "image/*");
```

**And start Activity for Result**

```
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, RequestCode.CROP_IMAGE);
```

Any feedback much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that sharing files often leads to permission problems, particular since `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is a dangerous permission on Android 6.0+ higher devices (requiring you to

Instead, you should follow the [sharing files training](http://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/index.html) and use [FileProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html) to create a Uri that other apps can read without the storage permissions (on your part or on the other app's part).

Comment: Thank you! FileProvider worked. I'm having trouble getting useful info back in onActivityResult(). In fact it's coming back with a result code of 0 for some reason. Investigating ...